# Is finding all primes less than n, doable in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np, np-complete

Bear in mind I'm almost a complete noob at complexity theory.

I was reading about how AKS Primality shows that numbers of size n can be shown to be prime or composite in polynomial time. Given that, does that imply finding all prime numbers less than a number n is also doable in polynomial time and thus the algorithm runs in FP. Additionally, does this imply that counting all primes less than n is not in #P?

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is a significant open question in complexity theory.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be a much better fit for [Computer Science StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)? I don't see the programming aspect that would make it a fit for this site.

Comment: @njuffa, fair enough, I'll post it over there

Comment: You're going from numbers of size n (bits, assumedly) to numbers less than n, so you're losing an exponential factor right there, making the problem trivially P

Answer (score 0):

well. What aks says it that primality testing for a number n is O(b^k) where b = log2(n) and k is some integer.
So, if your questions is is listing all the primes from 1 to n also O(b^k). Then the answer is trivially no because the number of primes less than n is O(n/logn). Therefore you would need O(n/log(n) ) just to list them
If your question is does there exist a k such that the complexity of listing all the primes less than n is in O(n^k).
Then the answer is trivially yes because the most trivial form of sieve is O(n^(1.5)).
If anything is unclear please let me know